# Python Regular Expression string exclusion

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup

Using beautfiulsoup to parse sourcecode for scraping:

```
tempSite = preSite+'/contact_us/'
print tempSite
theTempSite = urlopen(tempSite).read()
currentTempSite = BeautifulSoup(theTempSite)
lightwaveEmail = currentTempSite('input')[7]

#<input type="Hidden" name="bb_recipient" value="comm2342@gmail.com" />
```

How can I re.compile lightwaveEmail so that only comm2342@gmail.com is printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda going about it the wrong way. The reason its the wrong way is that you're using numbered indexes to find the tag you want - BeautifulSoup will find tags for you based on their tag, or attributes which makes it a lot simpler.

You want something like

```
tempSite = preSite+'/contact_us/'
print tempSite
theTempSite = urlopen(tempSite).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(theTempSite)
tag = soup.find("input", { "name" : "bb_recipient" })
print tag['value']
```

Comment: tagging and attributing helps tremendously, however I'm still not quite getting the output I'm looking for: In this case it's now printing [<input type="Hidden" name="bb_recipient" value="comm2342@gmail.com" />] - I want to explicitly splice the value field as the only output.

Comment: `.findAll()` returns a list. Use `soup.find('input', dict(name="bb_recipient", value=True))` to get the first found element.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Good catch, modified my answer.

Comment: `value=True` in the previous comment selects `<input>` that has `value` attribute to avoid exception on `tag['value']`.

Comment: Awesome. Great examples and helped me understand.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to get the value attribute from the tag object, then you can use it as a dictionary:

```
lightwaveEmail['value']
```

You can find more information about this in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20attributes%20of%20Tags).

If the question is how to find in the soup all `input` tags with such a value, then you can look for them as follows:

```
soup.findAll('input', value=re.compile(r'comm2342@gmail.com'))
```

You can find a similar example also in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Quick%20Start).